# Mapping multiple email recipients to MSCRM 2011 with ETL software using MSCRM API

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, data-migration

I am using Starfish ETL to map the "to" destination field that is "partylist" type.

What does partylist mean?

By default, it is the "to" destination field that is mapped with the default map they provide. But their is also the "torecipients" type "String(500). cc & bbc are also strings.

What I dont understand is the difference between the "to" & the "torecipients" columns, even with the description provided on the entity metadata 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309512.aspx

Into MSCRM database, you see the emails separated by ";" but even if trying to add hardcoded values separated with ";" or spaces or commas, only one of multiple recipients provided is inserted.

Does anyone know how I could do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the field `torecipients` is not used inside CRM 2011, most probably was used in earlier version of CRM like 3.0 and kept for upgrading purposes.

In fact its value is only filled when an email is created, when `to` field is updated the string value inside `torecipients` field doesn't reflect the changes of the new email addresses (just tested in a CRM online environment)

End of story: Ignore `torecipients` field.

Comment: Thanks, I am performing a migration & would like to know how to populate this 'to' field with multiple emails, also, if it is possible. I'm using an ETL tool for mapping DBs that seems to use the MSCRM 2011 API.

Comment: @Sébastien if you are using an ETL tool, you need to check if the ETL is able to manage `activityparty` fields (`to` is one of them, check this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328549.aspx)